# Time Reference in Reported Speech?

Tags: grammar, meaning, reported-speech

I quote what is written down in bold from a grammar book:
[image]

**"Time reference changes when we use reported speech.
For example:
Anne said, ‘I’m going swimming this afternoon.’ ➟ Anne told me that she was going swimming that afternoon."**
Let's suppose that 'Anne' told me she was going swimming at 8 a.m., and that I reported what she had said to someone else at 11 a.m. of the same day; *would it make sense* to say "she was going swimming **THAT** afternoon". I believe the listener would assume that 'Anne' has already went swimming, and that I am talking about a previous day, rather than the one we are in. Am I right or wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Anne told me she was going swimming this afternoon" means I spoke to Anne earlier but she is swimming later.

Comment: Thank you, but the reported speech says "that afternoon" not "this afternoon".

Comment: Right. I was trying to show you what would be correct. In the case you presented, it would be correct to say as I wrote it.

You cannot use "that afternoon" to mean today. It can only refer to a day other than today.

So if I said to someone, "Anne told me she was going swimming that afternoon", then I would certainly be talking about another day. You asked "would it make sense" and the answer is no, it would not. The sentence I wrote above is how to say it correctly.

Comment: Now you have added the picture, I see your confusion. The person spoke to me last week. When she spoke, she said "I am going swimming TODAY". But now it is a week later, so when I report the speech, I say "she said she was going swimming THAT day". However, if I spoke to her earlier TODAY and she said "I am going swimming TODAY" then I would say "she said she was going swimming TODAY" because it is still TODAY now.

Comment: My answer below makes this clear, I hope.

Answer (score 2):

There are several examples and questions in your original post, so I'll try to break them down.

Let us first assume this is all today. It is now 11am. I spoke with Anne at 8am. At 8am, Anne said, "I am going swimming this afternoon."

Now, at 11am, I can say, "I spoke to Anne this morning. *She said she was going swimming this afternoon.*"

If I said, "She said she was going swimming *that* afternoon", then there is some important context missing. We would first have to establish earlier in the conversation when "that" afternoon was.

So it might happen as follows:

> A: Ann didn't come to lunch on Monday. Do you know why?
>
> B: I spoke to Anne on Monday morning, actually. She said she was going
>   swimming that afternoon.

This would make sense.

Comment: Thank you, it is quite clear now. The problem with grammar books is that they don't provide examples in contexts, which cause us to get confused. I have already added a screenshot of the book from which I quoted to show you what I mean.